# retrofit calling json data but its response show null

Tags: android, retrofit

Here is my code any one help, why it shows response is null? There is some mistake which I cannot found.

```
   public void getAllTasksWithSuccess(){
    String url = ""+ RetrofitClient.baseURL +"here is my service code ";
    RetrofitClient.createRetrofitInstance();
    Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient.getCallObject("getTodaysTask",url);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            try {
                Log.i("TAG",response.body().string());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("tag2", "Failed : " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.ResponseBody.string()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.ra.ra.DashboardFragments.FragmentTasks$2.onResponse(FragmentTasks.java:83)
```

Comment: response is null or response.body() is null??

Comment: Check response code

Comment: yes... response.body() is null.

Comment: Then check response.code(). What does it show?

Comment: check your API in in api/http client i.e postman

Comment: but in this code the other method are working perfectly ..it giving json data on it response

Comment: if postman gives success response means, your java code having problem. Post your full code related to API calls.

Comment: when i put link on postmen it shows 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: If it gives 401 error code, it will surely give null response b'coz retrofit gives response only if you get success status code like 200.

Comment: So how i fix it ?

Comment: As 401 is not the right status code for api call success, using retrofit you will always get your response as null and your response will go to response.errorBody()...But there is one workaround if you want to try

Answer (score 0):

Add below class ServiceGenerator:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

public static final String API_BASE_URL = AppConstants.BASE_URL;


private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

public static Retrofit retrofit() {
    retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

And use below ErrorUtils class to parse your response's errorBody:

```
public class ErrorUtils {

public static ResponseBody parseError(Response<?> response) {
    Converter<ResponseBody, ResponseBody> converter =
            ServiceGenerator.retrofit()
                    .responseBodyConverter(ResponseBody.class, new Annotation[0]);

    ResponseBody error;

    try {
        error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new ResponseBody();
    }

    return error;
}
}
```

And now in your onResponse do as below:

```
public void getAllTasksWithSuccess(){
String url = ""+ RetrofitClient.baseURL +"here is my service code ";
RetrofitClient.createRetrofitInstance();
Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient.getCallObject("getTodaysTask",url);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
         if(response.isSuccessful()){
               // here your response.body() will not be null
         }else{
               // here your response.body() will be null
               // and here you might get your response in response.errorBody();


              ResponseBody res= ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
              System.out.println("Response is:"+ res.toString());
         }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.i("tag2", "Failed : " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
}
```